# Reshaping dataframe from categories cross-table to one with multi-index in the columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

### Problem statement

I am trying to turn a dataframe with a table that crosses categories with items at different dates into a dataframe with dates in the index and multiindex columns with categories as first level and items as the second level. Below you can find an example of original and target tables.

Is there a pythonic way to achieve this in Pandas?

### Input table

- All of the table is in the dataFrame data. Indices and columns are just integers*

|  | Category A | Category B | Category C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 31/12/2020 |  |  |  |
| item one | 10 | 100 | 1000 |
| item two | 20 | 200 | 2000 |
| 31/12/2021 |  |  |  |
| item one | 30 | 300 | 3000 |
| item two | 40 | 400 | 4000 |

### Desired output table

*Dates should be in the index and columns should be a multiindex of Category and item*

|  | Category A |  | Category B |  | Category C |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | **item one** | **item two** | **item one** | **item two** | **item one** | **item two** |
| 31/12/2020 | 10 | 20 | 100 | 200 | 1000 | 2000 |
| 31/12/2021 | 30 | 40 | 300 | 400 | 3000 | 4000 |

### Python code to create input dataframe

```
import pandas as pd

input_df = pd.DataFrame(
              index = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6],
              columns = [0,1,2,3],
              data = [
                 ["","Category A","Category B","Category C"],
                 ["31/12/2020","","",""],
                 ["item one",10,100,1000],
                 ["item two",20,200,2000],
                 ["31/12/2021","","",""],
                 ["item one",30,300,3000],
                 ["item two",40,400,4000],
              ]
           )
```

Comment: Your example dataframe does not have indexes, the headers are part of the data. Is this expected?

Comment: yes, that's how I have my input dataframe. It would be easy to set the index or columns to something else if that would make things easier. But I didn't think that would help so  thought I'd leave it untouched.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a complex reshape with a central `pivot`. I used the ability to be converted to date to identify the groups of rows:

```
out = (input_df
 .T.set_index(0).T
 .assign(date=lambda d: pd.to_datetime(d[''], errors='coerce').ffill())
 .loc[lambda d: pd.to_datetime(d[''], errors='coerce').ne(d['date'])]
 .pivot(index='date', columns='')
 .rename_axis(index=None, columns=(None, None))
)
```

Output:

```
           Category A          Category B          Category C         
             item one item two   item one item two   item one item two
2020-12-31         10       20        100      200       1000     2000
2021-12-31         30       40        300      400       3000     4000
```